# WPF : how create our own autogeneratedColumns in datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

i've got some tables in my application with some references to other tables, for example a product can have a product Type and just save the Product Type ID in the table.

I want to show a generic datagrid using autogenerated columns for showing all the data i want.
For example, i want to open my window with datagrid and show products. but i want also to show this same window but with an other table for example Person with a GenderType

It is working with simple data like String, int etc... but not with related data. how can I automatically showing a Combobox for selecting my data like the GenderType or ProductType ?

here's what i've tried :

XAML Code :

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="T_DataGrid"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}"
              Margin="10,10,10,8"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
              Grid.Row="1">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

PersonModel :

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public PersonModel(int genderType)
    {
        _GenderType = genderType;
    }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    private static int _GenderType { get; set; }

    public GenderModel GenderType { get; set; }
}
```

GenderModel :

```
`    public class GenderModel
    {
        public GenderModel() { }

        public int Type { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Type} -> {Description}";
        }

    }`
```

and then, my PersonViewModel witch is the datacontext of my window :

```
`        public PersonViewModel()
        {
            _genderList.Add(new GenderModel { Type = 1, Description = "Male" });
            _genderList.Add(new GenderModel { Type = 2, Description = "FeMale" });
            _genderList.Add(new GenderModel { Type = 3, Description = "What Ever You Want For My Own Peace" });

            DataCollection.Add(new PersonModel(1) { Age = 20,  Name = "Peter" });
            DataCollection.Add(new PersonModel(2) { Age = 22,  Name = "Lydia" });
            DataCollection.Add(new PersonModel(3) { Age = 30,  Name = "It is not your business because i'm not female or male" });

            foreach (var person in _dataCollection)
            {
                person.GenderType = _genderList.FirstOrDefault();
            }

        }


        private ObservableCollection<PersonModel> _dataCollection = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>();

        public ObservableCollection<PersonModel> DataCollection
        {
            get { return _dataCollection; }
            set => SetProperty(ref _dataCollection, value);
        }


        private List<GenderModel> _genderList = new List<GenderModel>();

    }`
```

Comment: I think you are working with wpf. Can u add your xaml?

Comment: Yes it is the first code text : a simple datagrid with autogenerated columns